# Wamp server alias won't load files

Tags: php, wamp, alias

I am using wamp server version 2.4
I have a zend project, and when i create virtual host it works like a charm (http://nasport.localhost/authentication/login). But i need to access it via my IP address (e.g. 127.0.0.1/nasport/). I made an alias in wamp, but when I go to that page, i get only ugly page without css, and login is not working too because it can't access other files. Here is my alias:

```
    Alias /nasport/ "d:/dev/php/nasport/public/" 

<Directory "d:/dev/php/nasport/public/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 

MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Please help me.

Comment: We cannot say much, since we do not know your content. But your description sounds like the Alias only covers _part_ of your content, not the style definitions for example. You should easily see that by either looking at the errors in your http servers error log file or by using your browsers debug console.

Comment: A wild _guess_ from my side (you really need to post more details in your question): you use an absolute reference to your style definitions, thus the Alias directive does not match. Always use _relative_ references to keep your content relocatable.

Comment: I have a zend project that is on location "d:/dev/php/nasport". In "nasport" folder i have folder "public" that contains folders css, img, js that contains all css, image and js files. And I guess that it can't access those files.

Comment: Sure, that is a typical layout, so what _are_ your references I asked about? Check the header section of your html pages for the style references in there and post those.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: See: that is an _absolute_ reference (note the leading `/`). Change it into a _relative_ reference (remove the leading `/`) and things will work. To understand what is going on you really should try what I suggested in my first comment. This is no magic, it is easy to understand once you see what is going on.

Comment: As an alternative to your `Alias` directive which does not work if you cannot change the way your styles are referenced inside your content you can do "request rewriting" instead inside your http server or use the http servers internal proxy facility. Both approaches can fix this issue too. However the best solution would be to use relative references, you always should prefer to solve the real cause of an issue, not its symptoms.

Comment: Are you trying to access your site from the internet rather than just on your PC, I see you have set an `Allow from all`. If so you should use you routers WAN Ip address and not 127.0.0.1. 127.0.0.1 is only available to address your local PC, it cannot be used from the internet. Every PC in the world is 127.0.0.1! You also have to port forward your router so that traffic is allowed through to you internal PC.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to access your site from another PC on your internal network or open the site up to the world?